# JVM error 545 incompatiable or corrupt filesystem in blackberry simulator 9981

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

while compiling my project on 9981 simulator using  blackberry 5.0. its show the error like "JVM error 545 incompatible or corrupt file system.
I could not even see the first screen of the simulator.
Can any one tell me what is the reason for this error and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

i have came across 5xx series error (on device havent tested on simulator) before to be exact got *507* and *523* which when did some digging it came out that the

- *507* comes when .cod files arent loaded properly through app-loader
- *523* when critical Java process was killed

but after a full wipe of OS everything came back to normal
comes out that the OS was corrupt or multiple re-installation left some scratches...i would recommend to check your stack trace or paste it here